# I've installing with Paytm production API details in my laravel project but still throwing on staging gateway

Tags: laravel, paytm

I've integrated paytm payment API in my laravel project, And I using the staging API details in the project and it's running perfectly with Test Kit. But when I'm using the production kit it still throwing me on staging payment gateway. Why does it happen? please help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate your issue, please mention which kit you are using? In the kit please make sure that this https://securegw.paytm.in/ baseurl is being used